# Why ApplicationException is thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex

I am just experimenting on Mutex and wrote the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Mutex_WaitOnewithTimeouts
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();
        private static int numOfThreads = 5;
        private static int numOfIterations = 3;
        private static Random rand = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[5];
            for (int num = 0; num < numOfThreads; num++)
            {
                threads[num] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadProc));
                threads[num].Name = String.Format("Thread{0}", num);
                threads[num].Start();
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void MyThreadProc()
        {
            for (int iteration = 0; iteration < numOfIterations; iteration++)
            {
                UseResource();
            }
        }

        private static void UseResource()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} accessing ", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            int time = (int)(rand.NextDouble() * 100);
            try
            {
                if (mut.WaitOne(time))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Yippie got mutex for {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                    Thread.Sleep((int)rand.NextDouble() * 5000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nopee.... Timeout occured for {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Exception is caught");
            }
            finally 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Releasing mutex for {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
               mut.ReleaseMutex();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting ApplicationException sometimes.. Can someone please help me if there is anything wrong with my code and also please explain when will this exception trigger.

Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code. I am getting this in the finally block when trying to release the mutex.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the top couple of lines from the exception and show what line it is being thrown on in your sample code.

Comment: `ApplicationException` is *normally* only seen when you personally create an exception derived from it. Are you sure it is `ApplicationException` you are seeing? Or are you seeing a derived exception, like `TargetInvocationException` or `WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException` instead?

Comment: What's the Message in the exception? Are there any inner exceptions? Have you looked at the stack trace for any clues?

Comment: Guess here: an ApplicationException could occur if you release a mutex that you do not hold.  Do you see the "Nopee..." console output before the exception?

Comment: @Gray Updated. Please check now

Comment: @sixlettervariables No... As u can see I am not creating any personal exception :(

Comment: @SteveWong Yes... I am getting that exception only when timeout is occured..

Comment: @Shrikey - see John's answer.  Only release the Mutex if you obtain it.

Comment: `System.Random` is not threadsafe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are releasing the mutex even if your WaitOne failed.  Move the ReleaseMutex call inside the if statement where you know you have the mutex obtained.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Koerner .. That worked  ... I was wondering.. Is there any way I can change my code so that the else part will execute ???

Comment: @Shrikey Just move the releaseMutex call up into the If statement.  Alternatively you could set a boolean value that you set to true when the lock is obtained and only release if that is true.

Comment: Wouldn't a better pattern here be to set a boolean in the `if and then in the finally do a `if (flag) mut.ReleaseMutex();`? If he just moves the release into the if, won't it not be released if there is a throw?

Answer (score 0):

@John's answer is correct but for posterity, I think a better pattern would be to set a boolean to be true in the `if` and then still do the `release` in the `finally` block but this time only do it if the boolean is true.  The problem is that if any of the `if` clause throws then the mutex will not be released.   I assume you will be adding more to the `if` clause than just a write and a sleep.

You always want to use a `try { ... } finally` pattern if you can, but just protect against the `waitOne()` call returning false.  Something like the following:

```
bool release = false;
try {
    if (mut.waitOne(time)) {
        release = true;
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} catch (AbandonedMutexException ex) {
    ...
} finally {
    ...
    if (release) {
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: no, this will not work.  Mutex's are synchronization mechanisms that ensure only one thread accesses an area of code at any one time.  If you set it to null in one thread, when the next thread gets to that code, it will throw a null reference exception.

Comment: Duh, right @John thanks.  I forgot that it was static.  I've changed by answer to use a boolean instead.