# Releasing the mutex.

Tags: .net, multithreading, mutex

"The Mutex class enforces thread identity, so a mutex can be released only by the thread that acquired it. By contrast, the Semaphore class does not enforce thread identity. "

This is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) description says ..  But according to my question [Application exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402464/why-applicationexception-is-thrown), I tried to release a mutex even when i dont obtain it. It showed me an exception when next thread is executed. Does it mean that the thread which dont have access to the mutex released it ??? Can someone please help me in understanding this concept and please direct me if I made anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the documentation says, the ApplicationException was thrown because a thread that did not own the mutex tried to release it. That does not mean that the mutex was released, just that the thread that tried to release it did not own it.

```
var mutex = new Mutex();
mutex.WaitOne();
var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
       try
       {
          mutex.ReleaseMutex(); //This will throw ApplicationException
       }
       catch (ApplicationException ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Failed to release mutex");
       }
    });

thread.Start();
thread.Join();

mutex.ReleaseMutex(); //No exception will be thrown here
```

In this example, the initial thread creates the mutex and acquires it. The second thread will be spun up, attempt to release it and fail. After it fails, the owning thread will release it.

**Update**

In your previous question, it's important to note that you are running that code with multiple threads and that the same race condition is present in each thread. Multiple threads may have failed to acquire the mutex while one thread held on to it, and so multiple threads will likewise fail to release it. Take the following path of execution as an example.

- Thread 1 acquires the mutex.
- Thread 2 fails to acquire the mutex because Thread 1 has it.
- Thread 3 fails to acquire the mutex because Thread 1 has it.
- Thread 3 attempts to release the mutex, throwing an ApplicationException because it doesn't own it.
- Thread 1 releases the mutex.
- Thread 2 attempts to release the mutex, throwing an ApplicationException because it doesn't own it.

The fact that Thread 3 blew up when it failed to release the mutex has no correlation to the fact that Thread 2 *also blew up by doing the same thing.*

Comment: If u can please execute the code in my previous question. U will notice that an exception is raised in the next thread.

Comment: But if u can just check the output for the code. Application exception is not thrown immediately after the thread releases the mutex which doesnt own it. The exception is delayed :(

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the concept a mutex you can imagine it as a drawer, and the thread that owns the mutex as the person that holds the key to that drawer. Only the person that holds the key to the drawer can unlock it, hence only the thread that acquired the mutex can release it.

When you try to release a mutex from a thread that doesn't own the mutex it's like someone trying to open someone else's drawer with a fake key, so an exception is thrown to catch the burglar!

That is all a mutex does, it prevents multiple threads from executing "protected code" (inside the drawer). Its name comes from "mutual exclusion", which means one thread at a time.